# Unity 5 C# GUI - Making a progress bar based on goal completion distance.

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a quick GUI Progress bar that shows your progress in the level.

This is the code I have now, what do I have to do to get it to work?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Distance : MonoBehaviour {

private float finalGoal_dist = 0.0f;
public Transform Player;
public Transform finalGoal;


public Vector2 pos = new Vector2(20, 40);
public Vector2 size = new Vector2(120, 120);
public Texture2D emptyTex;
public Texture2D fullTex;


void OnGUI(){
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x, size.y), emptyTex);
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x*t, size.y), fullTex);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    finalGoal_dist = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, finalGoal.position);
    print("Distance to Goal:" + finalGoal_dist);
}
}
```

Comment: The GUI isn't connected to the finalGoal_dist, I'm unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finalGoal_dist` is a private class level variable, meaning you can effectively use it anywhere in the `Distance` class. So you could just do:

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x*finalGoal_dist, size.y), fullTex);
```

However, you first want to map into the range [0,1] so your progress bar doesn't become longer than `size.x`. You can do this by first dividing `finalGoal_dist` by the initial distance between start and finish, I'll call this `initial_dist`.

```
float t = finalGoal_dist / initial_dist;
GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x*t, size.y), fullTex);
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason in my debug log the player distance from the goal counts down then counts up again despite the fact the goal is at the very end of the map. This is messing up the progress bar.

http://i.imgur.com/tiOa5nn.png

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what would cause this off the top of my head, but if you're still having problems with it I suggest opening another question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to store the initial distance since you want to show completion with a progress bar, and completion is somewhat relative.

So in the `Start()` method, store the initial distance in a new member variable:

```
float initialDistance;
void Start()
{
    initialDistance = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, finalGoal.position);
}
```

Then, in the `OnGUI()` method, first you should draw a big box for the total distance, then draw a smaller box over the first box for the completed distance.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x, size.y), emptyTex);
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0, size.x * (initialDistance / finalGoal_dist), size.y), fullTex);
}
```